# Problem with animation in Java swing - Pacman

Tags: java, swing, animation, 2d

I was trying to replicate the Pacman game and I came up with the player animation, then turn around according to where required and open and close the mouth in a loop. I wrote the code, and it works correctly as required. Only that it opens and closes its mouth when I hold down the keys (W, A, S, D) and not always. I don't understand where the mistake is .. This is my code for now:

```
package playerAnimation;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener  {
    
    Timer tm = new Timer(1,this);

    private String playerDirection="Right";
    private int playerX;
    private int playerY;
    private int playerSpeedX;
    private int playerSpeedY;
    
    private int spriteCounter = 0;
    private int spriteNum = 1;
    
    public BufferedImage playerUp, playerDown, playerLeft, playerRight, playerClosedMouth;
    public BufferedImage imagePlayer = null;
    
    public void getPlayerImage() {
        try {
            playerUp = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/imageUp.png"));
            playerDown = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/imageDown.png"));
            playerLeft = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/imageLeft.png"));
            playerRight = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/imageRight.png"));
            playerClosedMouth = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/closed.png"));
        }catch(IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer(1,this);
    
    
    public Animation() {
        getPlayerImage();
        tm.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    
    
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(imagePlayer,playerX,playerY,null);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        playerX=playerX+playerSpeedX;
        playerY=playerY+playerSpeedY;
        repaint();
    }
    

    
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                
                if(spriteNum==1) {
                    imagePlayer=playerUp;
                }
                if(spriteNum==2) {
                    imagePlayer=playerClosedMouth;
                }
                
                playerSpeedX=0;
                playerSpeedY=-1;
            }
            
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                
                if(spriteNum==1) {
                    imagePlayer=playerRight;
                }
                if(spriteNum==2) {
                    imagePlayer=playerClosedMouth;
                }
                
                playerSpeedX=1;
                playerSpeedY=0;
            }
            
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                
                if(spriteNum==1) {
                    imagePlayer=playerLeft;
                }
                if(spriteNum==2) {
                    imagePlayer=playerClosedMouth;
                }
                
                playerSpeedX=-1;
                playerSpeedY=0;
            }
            
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                
                if(spriteNum==1) {
                    imagePlayer=playerDown;
                }
                if(spriteNum==2) {
                    imagePlayer=playerClosedMouth;
                }
                
                playerSpeedX=0;
                playerSpeedY=1;
            }
            
            spriteCounter++;
            if(spriteCounter>10) {
                if(spriteNum==1) {
                    spriteNum=2;
                }
                else if(spriteNum==2) {
                    spriteNum=1;
                }
                spriteCounter=0;
            }
            
        }

    
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        

    }



    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

}
```

And the main:

```
package playerAnimation;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Animation player = new Animation();
        JFrame Window = new JFrame();
        
        Window.setTitle("playerAnimation");
        Window.setSize(600,400);
        Window.setVisible(true);
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Window.add(player);
    
    }

}
```

Here are the photos:

[playerClosedMouth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkw83.png)

[playerDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am6PQ.png)

[playerLeft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pjqm.png)

[playerRight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVD6m.png)

[playerUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD64A.png)

Comment: 1) A painting method should only paint the current state of the class, NOT change the state. Your current logic is changing the image to be painted. That logic should be moved to the listeners class. So basically there is no need for the "playerDirection" variable. Instead you just set the "imagePlayer" variable when the KeyEvent is handled. The painting method then just paints the image. 2) Your Timer fires too fast. 1ms is not practical. Maybe it fires too fast and repaint results get combined into one so you don't see the image changing. Try using 1000 to see if that works.

Comment: I did as you said. In the paintComponent method I left only g.drawImage (imagePlayer, playerX, playerY, null); instead in the keyPressed method I put two if's in each condition of the pressed key with (if spriteNum == 1) playerImage becomes playerUp for example, and ( if spriteNum == 2) playerImage becomes playerClosedMouth. This with all the conditions of key detection. Unfortunately nothing changes. The mouth animation only takes place when I hold down the keys.

Comment: Please either include the images or hotlink them from an URL, this way we can test the code as well. And also post the edited code with the suggestions made by camickr

Comment: Done. I added the photos and edited the code with the corrections made by camickr

Comment: `Timer timer` is never used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Please read the comments in the code to follow the changes made to display the basic packman player animation. 
See the todo comments for more enhancment recommendations:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener  {

    private int playerX , playerY, playerSpeedX, playerSpeedY;

    private boolean isMouthOpen; //flag to toggle mouth open / closed

    private static final Dimension P_SIZE = new Dimension(600,400);

    public BufferedImage playerUp, playerDown, playerLeft, playerRight, playerClosedMouth, imagePlayer;

    //publicly available images for the MRE
    private static final String IMAGE_UP ="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD64A.png",
                                IMAGE_DOWN ="https://i.stack.imgur.com/am6PQ.png",
                                IMAGE_LEFT ="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pjqm.png",
                                IMAGE_RIGHT = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVD6m.png",
                                IMAGE_CLOSED = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkw83.png"
                                ;

    public void getPlayerImage() {
        try {
            playerUp = ImageIO.read(new URL(IMAGE_UP));
            playerDown = ImageIO.read(new URL(IMAGE_DOWN));
            playerLeft = ImageIO.read(new URL(IMAGE_LEFT));
            playerRight = ImageIO.read(new URL(IMAGE_RIGHT));
            playerClosedMouth = ImageIO.read(new URL(IMAGE_CLOSED));
        }catch(IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Animation() {
        getPlayerImage();

        //initialize player image, location and speed
        imagePlayer = playerRight;
        playerX = 100; playerY = 100; playerSpeedX = 1; playerSpeedY = 0;
        isMouthOpen = true;
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        Timer tm = new Timer(100,this);
        tm.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //if mouth is open - draw mouth closed and vice versa
        BufferedImage  image = isMouthOpen ? playerClosedMouth : imagePlayer;
        g.drawImage(image, playerX, playerY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        checkBounds();
        playerX=playerX+playerSpeedX;
        playerY=playerY+playerSpeedY;
        isMouthOpen = ! isMouthOpen; //toggle mouth flag 
        //todo add control parameters to allow toggling mouth at a different rate 
        repaint();
    }

    //use key presses to change direction and player image 
    //todo: use key binding instead of KeyListener
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            playerSpeedX=0;
            playerSpeedY=-1;
            imagePlayer=playerUp;
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            playerSpeedX=1;
            playerSpeedY=0;
             imagePlayer=playerRight;
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            playerSpeedX=-1;
            playerSpeedY=0;
            imagePlayer=playerLeft;
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            playerSpeedX=0;
            playerSpeedY=1;
            imagePlayer=playerDown;
        }
    }

    private void checkBounds(){
        //todo change direction when player hits bounds 
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return P_SIZE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animation player = new Animation();
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Player Animation");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(player);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The mouth animation only takes place when I hold down the keys

if you want the animation to happen without holding the keys, then the logic to toggle the image needs to move to the Timer ActionListener so it changes at the same time you change the location of the image.

The (untested) logic might look something like:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
    playerOpenMouth = playerUp;
    playerSpeedX=0;
    playerSpeedY=-1;
}

...
```

And the logic to toggle the open/closed mouth image in the ActionListener might look something like:

```
if (openMouth)
    imagePlayer = playerOpenMouth;
else
    imagePlayer = playerClosedMouth;

openMouth = !openMouth;

playerX = playerX + playerSpeedX; // use white space to improve readability
playerY = playerY + playerSpeedY;
repaint();
```